# Facebook error on Sharing debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook on showing all content on sharing debugger. No idea what else can i do to make it fetch the right info.

> WARNINGS THAT SHOULD BE FIXED
>
> Inferred Property The
>   'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can
>   be inferred from other tags.
>
> Propriedade necessária em falta A
>   propriedade "og:type" é necessária, mas não está presente.
>
> Propriedade
>   inferida A propriedade "og:url" deve ser fornecida explicitamente,
>   mesmo que um valor possa ser inferido a partir de outras tags. Share
>
> App ID Missing The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided,
>   Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly
>   attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when
>   open the share dialog.

If you check the source of the page http://horizonteacores.com/desporto/artigo/55 you'll i have set the appID og:image, og:type and og:url. No idea what can be wrong.

You can see facebook debugger here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhorizonteacores.com%2Fdesporto%2Fartigo%2F55

I'm doing the same thing as the other websites i've done, and previews are working nice on the other websites.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are redirecting users (and crawlers) to horizonteacores.com/site/timezone and to the website's index afterwards. Probably because you set some cookie or local storage.

Facebook's crawler follows redirects (but does not handle cookies/local storage) and therefore you redirect it and/or render meta tags differently.

Check your server log files where you redirect those requests and add an exception to this redirects.

Comment: I tried checking if cookie was enabled without success.     if(navigator.cookieEnabled == false) {
        tz_offset = "+00:00";
    }
I need to set offset and timezone.

Comment: It's not just about cookies. You shouldn't redirect the requests to your site's index. If you require that redirect for whatever reason, make sure you do not redirect the Facebook crawler.

You can get all current IP addresses the crawler use via: 

whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route

Comment: It worked. If isn't a browser, i set a default timezone and skip redirect.

Answer (score 0):

for fb:app_id do this

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117" />
```

where 966242223397117 is the default app_id